# How to import data from txt file to mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have many txt files with various operations and functions and I need to import them one by one into my database (not separately into a table (so that *LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/mydata.txt' INTO TABLE PerformanceReport;* - doesn't work, I guess)).

How can I import/load into my datatables?
I use **unzip -p db_dump.sql.zip | mysql -u root -p my_db** for archive, maybe there is some code for txt?

Example of file

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------
-- --------------------------------------------------------------

INSERT INTO CAPITAL_ORIGIN (ORIGIN_NAME, ORIGIN_NAME_EN, LENDER_TYPE)
VALUES
('Origin Name', 'Accumulated salary', '1');

  -- --------------------------------------------------------------
  -- --------------------------------------------------------------

UPDATE TEXTS
SET CONTENT_EN = 'Certificate of Incorporation (Certificate of Incorporation or drafted from the registration'
WHERE TEXTTYPE = 'certificate_of_incorporation_file' AND PAGE_SLUG = 'registerlender_pr';

  -- --------------------------------------------------------------
  -- --------------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE ORGANIZATIONS
      ADD SPREAD_DIRECT_REDIRECTION TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0 NULL;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Mr_to_Web_LR`;
.......
```

Comment: Show some example of these textfiles content, and the result of their "importing".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is tehre any error message given when running that given command?

Comment: @Akina add in description

Comment: @NicoHaase What confuses me the most about LOAD DATA INFILE is that it has parameters for which table to insert. I have files with different procedures, and no exactly in tables

Comment: @NicoHaase as I think LOAD DATA INFILE tried to read txt as table with tab: simple comment in my txt in first line command think that is value:  ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '-- --------------------------------------------------------------' for column 'ID' at row 1

Comment: @Akina perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for! Felt something simple) Can you put answer and I mark it as a solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common command script. It must be simply executed.

[Executing SQL Statements from a Text File](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html).

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:
`LOAD DATA INFILE path/to/file.txt INTO TABLE tbl_tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ":";`